# Problemas com radiobutton em tabela(TR para cada um) - Aceita que todos estejam clicados

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho essa tabela e esses radios buttons. Acontece que eu seleciono mais de um radiobutton, ele não obedece a questão, de um selecionado o outro não.

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.RadioButton("Improdutivo-Reagendar","Improdutivo-Reagendar")Improdutivo-Reagendar</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.RadioButton("Improdutivo-PDV Não Apto","Improdutivo-PDV Não Apto")Improdutivo-PDV Não Apto</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.RadioButton("Improdutivo-Comercial","Improdutivo-Comercial")Improdutivo-Comercial</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.RadioButton("Improdutivo-Infra Estrutura","Improdutivo-Infra Estrutura")Improdutivo-Infra Estrutura</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.RadioButton("Finalizado","Finalizado")Finalizado</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: você pode explicar um pouco melhor o que esta acontecendo, talvez adicionar print algo do genero ?

Comment: Eles devem possuir o mesmo nome e os valores representando cada um.

Comment: Otto, eu posso, por exemplo clicar e checar todos de uma vez. Quanto ao FCCDias, como eu atribuo um nome a RadioButton criados por Helpers(@Html.RadioButton)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todos devem possuir o mesmo **nome** e o **valor** são diferentes para que você recupere tal valor, ou seja, para que você selecione somente um dos valores o nome é obrigatóriamente iguais. Se você for produzir outro grupo de radio coloque outro nome e assim por diante

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.RadioButton("selecao", "Improdutivo-Reagendar")Improdutivo-Reagendar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.RadioButton("selecao", "Improdutivo-PDV Não Apto")Improdutivo-PDV Não Apto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.RadioButton("selecao", "Improdutivo-Comercial")Improdutivo-Comercial</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.RadioButton("selecao", "Improdutivo-Infra Estrutura")Improdutivo-Infra Estrutura</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.RadioButton("selecao", "Finalizado")Finalizado</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Referência*

- [HTML Forms and Input](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: Quando falei no comentário, ainda não estava para mim a resposta. Agora resolveu tudo.